# How do I add envrionment variables for sudo/root?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I just learned that root's home is `/root` and I need to add some environment variables. I'm on an Ubuntu box, so should I add the environment variables to `/root/.profile` or `/root/.bashrc` or something else? I thought `.profile` would be it, but it already has some code which I've never seen before and I didn't want to edit the wrong file

Comment: `export VAR=data` in `/root/.profile`

Comment: Just add a new line in the end and add the exports you need.

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov `sudo` doesn't execute the profile.

Comment: I strongly suggest that if you *just learned that root's home is /root*, you avoid making modifications to anything related to root until you study the topic in detail. root has access that can really cause problems, and if you're not very knowledgeable about what you're doing you can render the computer unusable without a format and reinstall. With that being said, this question belongs on [ubuntu.se] or [su].

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.